# In Angular 11, how to HTTP POST application/json to AWS Lambda via API Gateway?

Tags: json, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I have an angular application I plan to host in AWS Amplify. It calls into Lambda functions for its REST API. I have a test application that is mostly successful, but it cannot do this one thing: POST JSON data to the hosted URI.

In the browser, I have an Angular client that has one button and when clicked, calls into `HttpClient.post` or `HttpClient.request`. I have multiple backend servers I've tested with: (1) NestJs/Express, (2) `sam local start-api` and (3) AWS hosted. The local `sam` server and the hosted environment are in sync and use the same `template.yaml`. All three servers accept `Content-Type` of `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Every combination of `Content-Type`, server instance and HttpClient method (`post` or `request(“POST”,...)`) works except Json in the hosted lambda function. It appears to be rejected immediately.

The call never makes it to the Cloudwatch logs, which I'm guessing means it's somehow malformed and filtered by I don't know what. I'm quite new to AWS and unfamiliar with its particularities, so I'm unsure what logging I can turn on in the hosted environment to capture this. It fails so quickly never reaching the logs let alone my code, I'm very curious what about it is a problem.

Curl with Json also works: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" ...`.

In summary, when POST'ing either Json or Form styles with `.post()` or `.request()` methods to non-AWS and local AWS web server, everything is dandy. Form style POST to AWS hosted (via API Gateway) works, too. Command line hand crafted POST with Json also works with AWS hosted (via API Gateway).

Only POST to AWS hosted from ***Angular*** does not work.

ETA Here’s a code snippet:

```js
const URI_LOCAL = “/api/music”;
const URI_HOSTED = “https://…amazonaws.com/Prod/api/music”;
const headers_j = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const album = {"title":"Mullet Beginnings","band":"The Wallabys”};
const body_j = JSON.stringify(album);

// This fails
let res_j$ = this.http.post<any>(URI_HOSTED, body_j, { headers: headers_j });

// This works
const headers_x = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
const body_x = 'title=Dancing Beers&band=Evils Ypsley’;
let res_x$ = this.http.post<any>(URI_HOSTED, body_x, { headers: headers_x });
```

I’ve also tried passing `album` instead of `body_j`. Both options (object or JSON string) work for URI_LOCAL. Neither work for URI_HOSTED.

Someone somewhere must have successfully POST’ed Json to an AWS hosted environment from Angular. Any tips on what I’ve done wrong?

[ETA] Here's the error log from the browser console:

```js
[Error] Preflight response is not successful
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://_SNIP_.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/rebuild due to access control checks.
[Log] POST: (main.js, line 194)
 HttpErrorResponse
  error: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, position: 0, totalSize: 0, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, …}
  headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map}
  message: "Http failure response for https://_SNIP_.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/rebuild: 0 Unknown Error"
  name: "HttpErrorResponse"
  ok: false
  status: 0
  statusText: "Unknown Error"
  url: "https://_SNIP_.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/rebuild"
[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (rebuild, line 0)
```

| client | content-type | server | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HttpClient.post | json | aws hosted | Failure |
| HttpClient.request | json | aws hosted | Failure |
| curl | json | aws hosted | Success |
| HttpClient.post | json | sam local | Success |
| HttpClient.post | json | nestjs | Success |
| HttpClient.post | x-www-form | aws hosted | Success |
| HttpClient.post | x-www-form | sam local | Success |
| HttpClient.post | x-www-form | nestjs | Success |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like  [CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) issue.

You need to not only enable CORS within the API Gateway but your Lambda API GAteway response MUST also include the access-control headers.

Your response should look something like this:

```
response = {
        statusCode: 204,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
        },
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This was it exactly. I edited your example slightly to match what I used.

Comment: Awesome. This caused me many hours of headaches a while back.

Comment: 24 hours of beating my head against the wall. So, yeah, I'm right there with you. So much magic to make everything work end to end. I guess I'll never forget about CORS, now. I thought it was solely for client cross-site scripting and not interrogating the server for functionality.

Comment: I knew about CORS, what I didn't know was I had to return the headers in my response. Glad it got resolved.